# Insert number in Powershell replace

Tags: regex, powershell

Using powershell I want to replace a specific numeric part of a string with another number.

It's best to describe this problem with an example.

```
$s = '   First part: 65 Second Part'

###################################################################
# this generates "       First part: sixty-six Second Part"       #
###################################################################
$s -replace '^(\s*First part:\s+)[0-9]+(.*)$', '$1sixty-six$2'

###################################################################
# But I want to generate"    First part: 66 Second Part"          #
###################################################################
$s -replace '^(\s*First part:\s+)[0-9]+(.*)$', '$166$2'
```

It doesn't work.

How do I specify "$1 followed by the number 66" as opposed to "$166"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this syntax: `${1}66$2`

Output:

```
'   First part: 66 Second Part'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$s -replace '^(\s*First part:\s+)[0-9]+(.*)$', '${1}66$2'
```

or

```
$s -replace '^(?<first>\s*First part:\s+)[0-9]+(.*)$', '${first}66$1'
```

Both are similar, except that the second one uses a named group.

I am not sure what you are trying to do ( the example seems cooked up) but there must be easier way to do what you want and also you can make use of

```
$`
```

and

```
$'
```

to signify the portions before and after a match respectively.

Comment: @AndyArismendi - Yeah thanks. Shucks how come you answer so soon :) I thought there was no other answer yet.